how to add indexOn to realtime database emulators
I'm trying to add .indexOn to fireabase.json for using sort and filter on realtime database emulator. But no matter what I do same error, error code below, keep occuring.
InvalidArgumentError: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "t", for path "/test", to the rules
I read official document but no clear instruction of where to write rules in firebase.json was found.
Please teach me what I'm doing wrong.
I'm working on python and Below are my attemp which non of it worked.
Operation I want to achieve
test = db.reference('test').order_by_child("t").get()

Realtime database structure
test->1->{t : timestamp, h : list of string}
      2->{t : timestamp, h : list of string}

firebase.json structure before rule
"emulators": {
"auth": {
  "port": 9099
},
"functions": {
  "port": 5001
},
"firestore": {
  "port": 8080
},
"hosting": {
  "port": 5000
},
"ui": {
  "enabled": true
},
"singleProjectMode": true,
"database": {
  "port": 9000
},
}

Attemp1: place rules under database
place rules inside database
"database": {
  "port": 9000,
  "rules" : {
    "test" : {".indexOn" : ["t"]}
  }
}

Attemp2: place rules under emulators
place rules under emulators
"emulators": {
"rules" : {
    "test" : {".indexOn" : ["t"]}
  },
}

Attemp3: change indexOn value from list of string to string
change value of indexOn to single string instead of list of string
"emulators": {
"rules" : {
    "test" : {".indexOn" : "t"}
  },
}


After extra attempt I was able to solve the issue by following answer on question below.
Realtime database emulator ignores database.rules.json

created realtime database rule file called database.rules.json and wrote below
{
"rules": {
".read": false,
".write": false,
"test" : {".indexOn" : ["t"]}
}
}

on .firebaserc file added database setting

on firebase.json added database setting


